# How to calculate RMSE for two groups of a dataset in R

Tags: r

I want help to calculate the RMSE of two groups from the  dataset looking like this:

```
structure(list(machine = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
    measured = c(14.47, 15.33, 18.56, 14.89, 17.24, 16.25, 13, 
    20.52, 18.06, 13.09, 16.88, 15.92, 14.47, 18.63, 13.88, 16.32, 
    13.83, 11.67, 13.42), predicted = c(15.83, 16, 17.87, 14.21, 
    17.77, 14.14, 12.01, 19.31, 16.98, 13.19, 15.6, 17.16, 16.07, 
    17.38, 17.99, 17.86, 18.54, 10.79, 16.06)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

I want to calculate RMSE for each Machine and if possible add it to my scatterplot.

I attempted this

```
fr <- read.csv(file.choose())

ggplot(fr, aes(measured, predicted, colour = machine)) +
  geom_point(size=2)+
  geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE) +
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label = paste(after_stat(eq.label),
                                 after_stat(rr.label), sep = "*\", \"*")))+
  theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=16))+
  theme(axis.line = element_line(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

I couldn’t find a way to automatically calculate the RMSE for my model.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(fr)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(fr, 20))`.

Comment: Thanks I learned how to make a reproducible example and I hope it is now better than before

Answer (score 1):

*In the future, please heed the comment and post your sample data as **text** using `dput`, not a screenshot.*

---

This is a classic "split-apply-combine" problem:

1. Split the data by machine type
2. Apply the function you want to use, in this case RMSE
3. Combine the results.

There are many, many ways to do this, using various libraries, such as `dplyr`. If you search for "split apply combine" and the `dplyr` tag on this site, you will find many examples.

Here is one solution using base R, using a somewhat-fancy technique from the discipline of "functional programming":

```r
rmse <- function(meas, pred) {
  sqrt(mean((meas - pred)^2))
}

apply_columns <- function(func, use_names = FALSE) {
  function(data) {
    if (!use_names) {
      data <- unname(data)
    }
    do.call(func, data)
  }
}

machine_rmse <- by(fr, fr$Machine, apply_columns(rmse), simplify = FALSE)
```

The resulting `groups` object is a list, which you can convert to a data frame and then use in your GGPlot routine:

```r
machine_rmse <- data.frame(
  name = names(machine_rmse),
  val = unlist(as.list(machine_rmse)))
```

However it's unclear from your question how exactly you want to display this information in your plot, so I can't advise further on how to incorporate this with `ggplot` code.

Comment: Is it `apply_colwise` or `apply_columns`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas good catch, I meant `apply_columns`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way `by`. The idea of using `by` must be credited to [shadowtalker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74470214/8245406).

```r
measured <- c(4.37, 3.36, 2.5, 2.96, 4.31, 3.69)
predicted <- c(4.47, 3.07, 3, 3.95, 3.3, 3.59)
machine <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))
fr <- data.frame(machine, measured, predicted)

rmse <- function(data) {
  x <- data[[1]]
  y <- data[[2]]
  sqrt(mean((x - y)^2))
}

rmse <- by(fr[-1], fr$machine, rmse)
data.frame(rmse = unclass(rmse))
#>        rmse
#> A 0.3386739
#> B 0.8185760
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For one off tasks, I'd go for the simplicity of `tidyverse()`. Though, if this is a regular task, then functional programming is the way to go.

@Rui Barradas's "fr" dataframe

```
measured <- c(4.37, 3.36, 2.5, 2.96, 4.31, 3.69)
predicted <- c(4.47, 3.07, 3, 3.95, 3.3, 3.59)
machine <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))
fr <- data.frame(machine, measured, predicted)

fr %>%   
  group_by(machine) %>% 
  summarise(rmse = sqrt(mean((measured - predicted)^2)))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  machine  rmse
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A       0.339
2 B       0.819
```

If you intend on plotting the RMSE on the graph, then change the `summarise()` to `mutate()` and the data.frame is preserved and can be passed straight to `ggplot()`

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   machine [2]
  machine measured predicted  rmse
  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 A           4.37      4.47 0.339
2 A           3.36      3.07 0.339
3 A           2.5       3    0.339
4 B           2.96      3.95 0.819
5 B           4.31      3.3  0.819
6 B           3.69      3.59 0.819
```